# Any method to get a size of arangodb collection?

Tags: arangodb

I'm looking for a way to measure the total size of a collection.
Is there equivalent method for arangodb like `db.collection.totalSize()` or `db.collection.stats()` in mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyArango.collection.Collection.figures()` solves the problem.